# How do I call a Javascript function outside of another Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function that's supposed to toggle an animation when clicked by calling another function outside of it.

```
function MyFunction(id) {
    var target = document.getElementById(id);
    var on = true;

    this.startMe = function() {
        //animation code
        on = true;
    }
    this.stopMe = function() {
        //animation code
        on = false;
    }
    this.toggleMe = function() {
        if (on) this.stopMe();
        else this.startMe();
    }
    target.addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.toggleMe();
    }, false);
}
```

The problem lies in the toggleMe and addEventListener functions. "this" refers to the function itself and not the one containing it, which is what I need it to reference. How can I work around this?

Comment: Assign the outer `this` to a variable, e.g. `var MyFunctionId = id;` and use it inside the addEventListener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy fix is to use a closure variable as given below

```
function MyFunction(id) {
    var self = this;
    var target = document.getElementById(id);
    var on = true;

    this.startMe = function () {
        //animation code
        on = true;
    }
    this.stopMe = function () {
        /animation code
        on = false;
    }
    this.toggleMe = function() {
        if (on) this.stopMe();
        else this.startMe();
    }
    target.addEventListener('click', function() {
        //this refers to the element here not the instance of MyFunction
        //use a closure variable
        self.toggleMe();
    }, false);
}
```

---

Another solution is to pass a custom execution context to the callback using [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/) - you can use [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) also but not supported in [IE < 9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Browser_compatibility)

```
function MyFunction(id) {
    var target = document.getElementById(id);
    var on = true;

    this.startMe = function () {
        //animation code
        on = true;
    }
    this.stopMe = function () {
        //animation code
        on = false;
    }
    this.toggleMe = function () {
        if (on) this.stopMe();
        else this.startMe();
    }
    //use Function.bind() to pass a custom execution context to 
    target.addEventListener('click', jQuery.proxy(function () {
        // this refers to the element here not the instance of MyFunction
        //use a closure variable
        this.toggleMe();
    }, this), false);
}
```

---

Also use [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)/[on('click')](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to register the click handler instead of [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

```
    $(target).on('click', jQuery.proxy(function () {
        // this refers to the element here not the instance of MyFunction
        //use a closure variable
        this.toggleMe();
    }, this), false);
```

Comment: Should be applied within `toggleMe()` as well, no?

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I never thought of creating a variable to hold the original function. I'll mark as the answer when available.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add another variable with a reference to `this` but with a different name; then you can use that in your functions.

```
function MyFunction(id) {
    var self = this;

    var target = document.getElementById(id);
    var on = true;

    this.startMe = function() {
        on = true;
    }

    this.stopMe = function() {
        on = false;
    }

    this.toggleMe = function() {
        if (on) self.stopMe();
        else self.startMe();
    }

    target.addEventListener('click', function() {
        self.toggleMe();
    }, false);
}
```

My personal preference is to take it even one step further and continue to use `self` everywhere that makes sense:

```
function MyFunction(id) {
    var self = this;

    var target = document.getElementById(id);
    var on = true;

    self.startMe = function() {
        on = true;
    }

    self.stopMe = function() {
        on = false;
    }

    self.toggleMe = function() {
        if (on) self.stopMe();
        else self.startMe();
    }

    target.addEventListener('click', function() {
        self.toggleMe();
    }, false);
}
```